# Почему валидатор сообщает об ошибке?

Tags: html, css, валидация

Доброго всем.
Есть знаменитый валидатор HTML кода - validator.w3.org.
Но почему он на такую строку сообщает об ошибке?
(Ошибка: "неуместно поставленный знак "**>**"")

```
<img src="images/candle_right.jpg"
     style="position: absolute; top:120px; left:10px; z-index:0;">
```

А здесь "ошибочно поставлен "**>**"", который после 16px;

```
<div style="height:16px;"></div>
```

Хотелось бы понять, почему это считается ошибками?

Comment: Поставьте перед ним пробел.

Comment: Что!? style в коде? Да я тебе сейчас руки на место вправлю!

Показывай полный код. По отлетевшему сапогу не всегда можно сказать жив ли его владелец.

Comment: 1. Все зависит от типа сайта, который вы валидируете: HTML 4, HTML 5, XHTML?
2. В описание, у тегу img стоит обязательный атрибут alt, которого нет.
3. Приводите полное описание (или скрин) того, что вам говорит валидатор, мне кажется, ошибка и описание звучат по-другому совсем. 

В остальном, если я добавляю alt к тегу img, у меня валидация проходит успешно на HTML5. При XHTML может требовать завершение одиночного тега как <img src="" alt="" ***/>*** и, если не ошибаюсь, отсутствие пустых тегов (считать их одиночными).

Comment: Код позиционируется как - HTML 4  
• [Cсылка на результаты валидатора][1]

  [1]: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=icar-soft.ru&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

• [Полный код (в браузере нажать CTRL+U)][2]

  [2]: http://icar-soft.ru

Comment: По ошибкам, если читать, что пишет валидатор, то все становится понятным:

1. Line 44, Column 7: у всех тегов style должен присутствовать атрибут type: <style type="text/css"> ...
2. Line 191, Column 130: В секции HEAD не могут быть элементы отображения, в данном случае DIV
3. Line 220, Column 6: Комментарий в комментарие, два раза подряд <!-- без окончания
4. Line 226, Column 119 + еще таких штук 14: У вас тег FONT являеся инлайновым, а в инлайновые пихать блочные нельзя. В данном случае куча Тегов DIV внутри инлайнового FONT.

Comment: 5. У изображений должны быть атрибуты ALT
6. Line 336, Column 44: атрибут rel есть только у ссылок, но не у div
7. Line 448, Column 13: Атрибут Align должен иметь значние